# Adding XML Comments using C + libxml++

Tags: c, xml

I am using libxml++-2.6 in C to create a really simple XML doc.

What is the technique for adding:

- comments before the root node?
- comments inside a node?

.

```
root_node = xmlNewNode( NULL, BAD_CAST "root" );
xmlDocSetRootElement( doc, root_node );

dtd = xmlCreateIntSubset(doc, BAD_CAST "root", NULL, BAD_CAST "root.dtd");

// neither of these seem to work

xmlNewComment( BAD_CAST "My Company, LLC" );

xmlNewDocComment    ( doc, BAD_CAST "My Company, LLC" );
```

Comment: That is not libxml++ code. That is libxml code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before this got moved here I had posted my own answer in StackOverflow.  Sorry to post it as an answer, but you can't do formatted inopput in comments.  :-)

This has worked for me;

```
root_node = xmlNewNode( NULL, BAD_CAST "root" );
xmlDocSetRootElement( doc, root_node );

//==========================================================================
// Comment block ABOVE the root node
//==========================================================================
cur_node = xmlAddPrevSibling( root_node, xmlNewComment( BAD_CAST copyright ));
           xmlAddNextSibling( cur_node,  xmlNewComment( BAD_CAST generated ));

cur_node = x

mlNewChild( root_node, NULL, BAD_CAST "Model" , BAD_CAST "FRED" );

//==========================================================================
// Comment block inside the root node but ABOVE the Model node
//==========================================================================
cur_node = xmlAddPrevSibling( root_node, xmlNewComment( BAD_CAST modinfo ));
           xmlAddNextSibling( cur_node,  xmlNewComment( BAD_CAST more_modinfo ));
```

Notice that as you add a node, you put the comment before it then put additional linesof comment below that comment but still before the new doc/child element.

Also notice, these comments can be outside the root node and not inside a visible node thatis a sibling of root.

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TEST SYSTEM "testsystem.dtd">
<!--Copyright (c) 2012 SuperTechnology, LLC.-->
<!--Generated Jan 20 2012 16:15:11-->
<root_node>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

int
main()
{
    xmlDocPtr foo = xmlNewDoc("1.0");
    xmlNodePtr com = xmlNewDocComment(foo, "bla bla");
    xmlNodePtr ins = xmlNewDocComment(foo, "more bla");
    xmlNodePtr roo = xmlNewDocNode(foo, NULL, "test", NULL);

    xmlDocSetRootElement(foo, com);
    xmlAddSibling(foo, roo);
    xmlAddChild(roo, ins);

    xmlDocDump(stdout, foo);
    return 0;
}
```

which results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--bla bla-->
<test><!--more bla--></test>
```